# Duplicate modules of same version in webpack build

Tags: javascript, webpack, yarnpkg

I work on an application using **Webpack** (4.12) to build modules installed with **yarn** (1.2.1). It is controlled by `yarn.lock`, use a list of internal (company) modules that has their own `yarn.lock` files and so on.

I found that modules of same version are duplicated a lot in the application bundle. Like `lodash` being included **9 times**. I started looking into the versions and found that the 9 copies is just 2 different versions of `lodash`. Then I looked into what dependencies included them, here is the result for what modules dependencies on `lodash` (with alias names):

```
(^4.16.4 / 4.17.4) application
(^4.17.2 / 4.17.5) @grp/libA
(^4.16.4 / 4.17.4) @grp/libA / @grp/libB
(^4.16.4 / 4.17.4) @grp/libA / @grp/libC
(^4.17.4 / 4.17.5) @grp/libD
(^4.16.4 / 4.17.4) @grp/libD / @grp/libE
(^4.17.2 / 4.17.5) @grp/libF
(^4.16.4 / 4.17.4) @grp/libF / @grp/libG
(^4.16.4 / 4.17.4) @grp/libF / @grp/libG
```

The numbers in brackets show the version stated in `package.json`, and the actual version that is in `node_modules` (installed with `yarn install`).

I understand that modules of different versions might need to be duplicated to avoid errors, but even if yarn has the sub modules (like `lodash` under `@grp/libA / @grp/libB` and `@grp/libA / @grp/libC`) installed in each modules own `node_modules`, shouldn't webpack see that they include the same version of lodash and at least reduce it down to just the two copies for `4.17.4` and `4.17.5`?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, on a project using the following structure:

```
src/
node_modules/
  |_ ...
  |_ ui
      |_ node_modules
      |_ src/
```

To prevent duplicating vendors, I used the `resolve` property such as:

```
{
    resolve: {
        modules: [
            path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
            path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/ui/node_modules'),
        ],
    },
}
```

More details are available on [the official doc](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvemodules), but to sum it up, it forces Webpack to check dependencies from these folders, in this exact order.

Hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

Here are some steps that can help you reduce duplicated packages in your webpack build. Let's take your example where `lodash` is bundled several times.

- Manually upgrade or downgrade packages depending `lodash` so you get as few versions as possible when running `npm ls lodash` or `yarn list lodash` in your `src`directory. Example output for `npm`:

  my-repo@0.0.1
  ├─┬ module-1@1.0.0
  │ └── lodash@x.x.x
  ├─┬ module-2@A.B.C
  │ └── lodash@x.x.x
  └── lodash@x.x.x
- Then, run `npm dedupe` or `yarn dedupe` so the package manager does the job of resolving duplicate depencies. You should then see a "deduped" mention next to the relevant packages:

  my-repo@0.0.1
  ├─┬ module-1@1.0.0
  │ └── lodash@x.x.x deduped
  ├─┬ module-2@A.B.C
  │ └── lodash@x.x.x deduped
  └── lodash@x.x.x

You may also try to remove package-lock.json and `npm` or `yarn install` all dependencies again from scratch to minimize duplicates with different versions.