# External Library: ReferenceError: React is not defined

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babel-loader

There is **external package** and **main application**. Both uses webpack and babel. External package uses webpack for building and has react in it.

External lib **babel.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    [
      '@babel/preset-env',
      {
        modules: false,
      },
    ],
    '@babel/preset-react',
  ],
  plugins: ['emotion', '@babel/syntax-dynamic-import'],
};
```

External lib **webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');

const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

const config = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'index.js',
    assetModuleFilename: 'assets/[contenthash][ext][query]',
    clean: true,
  },
  externals: {
    react: 'React',
    'react-dom': 'ReactDOM',
    emotion: 'emotion',
    reactEmotion: 'react-emotion',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/i,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|png|jpg|gif)$/i,
        type: 'asset',
      },
    ],
  },
};

module.exports = () => {
  if (isProduction) {
    config.mode = 'production';
  } else {
    config.mode = 'development';
  }
  return config;
};
```

Main React application uses this package:

```
import('EXTERNAL_PACKAGE_NAME').then((chat) => {
    // code does not reaches this line
    debugger;
    const a = chat.ReactFromModule === React;
});
```

Main app **webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = () => {
  const nodeEnv = process.env.NODE_ENV;
  const isProd = nodeEnv === 'production';

  return {
    mode: nodeEnv,
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.css', '.styl'],
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
          include: [res('src'), /node_modules\/(?!{EXTARNAL_PACKAGE_NAME})/],
          use: ['thread-loader', 'babel-loader'],
        },
      ],
    },
  };
};
```

In that case got error:

```
index.js:2 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: React is not defined
```

I've tried to use webpack config **externals** field, but this does not helps.

I've tried to add libraryTarget to external package config

```
  output: {
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    library: 'Chat',
    umdNamedDefine: true,
  }
  externals: {
    react: 'react',
    'react-dom': 'reactDOM',
    emotion: 'emotion',
    reactEmotion: 'react-emotion',
  },
```

and got error:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'reactDOM' in PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the external library the one which is supposed to provide React? You configured the `externals` field with React.

From the [webpack documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/):

> The externals configuration option provides a way of excluding
> dependencies from the output bundles. Instead, the created bundle
> relies on that dependency to be present in the consumer's (any
> end-user application) environment. This feature is typically most
> useful to library developers, however there are a variety of
> applications for it.

This means your library is relying on another package to provide React too.

Check out this SO answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54888897/8050896 , it might be helpful to force webpack to resolve modules.

```
{
    resolve: {
        modules: [
            path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
            path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/ui/node_modules'),
        ],
    },
}
```

Comment: No, this library must rely on consumer to have React on it...

Comment: The main problem that i have all settings in external library webpack.config
but main application still not provide react, or react verstions are not the same...